# Split string/output into sentences ('.', '?', '!' only) and print only first sentence

Tags: python

I'm trying to split (variable) output `restext` into individual sentences (delimiters are '.', '?' and '!' for this exercise), and print only the first sentence (i.e. take output `restext`, look for first occurrence of either '.', '?' or '!' and print the first full sentence). **Without the use of external libraries**

I've tried

```py
printtext = restext.replace('?',' ').replace('!',' ').replace('.',' ').split()
print(printtext);
```

For example:

```py
restext = "Hello my dear! How have you been? I was wondering how you are. Do let me know how you are!"
```

I will get

```
[Hello, my, dear, How, have, you, been, I, was, wondering, how, you, are, Do, let, me, know, how, you, are]
```

But I'm looking for

`"Hello my dear!"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to replace each sentence ending character with itself plus another character that won't be in the text, for example `#`. Then you can split on that character to get the individual sentences:

```py
restext = "Hello my dear! How have you been? I was wondering how you are. Do let me know how you are!"
sentences = restext.replace('?','?#').replace('!','!#').replace('.','.#').split('#')
printtext = sentences[0]
print(printtext)
```

Output:

```
Hello my dear!
```